# Push Notifications to Android App

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an android app connected to FCM(firebase cloud messaging) for sending notifications . However , when the app is in background , it doesn't apply
custom notifications. I think this is because it does not enter OnMessageReceived method . Whats the solution for this ? As i read somewhere it can be done using HTTP Api but i am not sure of how to go about it ? Please help.Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether the method `onMessageReceived` is called is dependent on the notification payload.

See 'Handling Messages' section in FCM docs [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive).

> **Handling messages**
>
> **onMessageReceived** is provided for most message types, with the following exceptions:
>
> Notification messages delivered when your app is in the background. In this case, the notification is delivered to the device’s system tray. A user tap on a notification opens the app launcher by default.
>   Messages with both notification and data payload, both background and foreground. In this case, the notification is delivered to the device’s system tray, and the data payload is delivered in the extras of the intent of your launcher Activity.

In summary, if the app is in **foreground**, then `onMessageReceived` will always be called. If the app is in **background**, then `onMessageReceived` will only be called if the notification payload is `data` only.

So to answer your question, if you must have `onMessageReceived` every time regardless if the app is in foreground or background state, then set your notification payload to contain `data` only.

Comment: how to set the notification payload to contain data only?

Comment: Do u mean if i am sending notification through my app server in a json code , than i should use data object , However , if i am sending the messages directly through FCM not using the server then how should i set the payload to data only , Please answer .

Comment: @DivyangShah see https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages. It details the message types, and how to send data messages.

Comment: i already read that article but is shows only with the use of json , im asking if there is a way you are aware in which i can send data messages straight from the firebase console , not using JSon or HTTp api and at the same time avoiding the above problem.Thank you